# Kibana 4 - Click through a visualization to the data

Tags: kibana, dashboard

I created a dashboard in Kibana 4 with a pie chart. I'd like to be able to "get to the data" that the pie chart represents. Let's say it highlights success and failures of a specific application in the log. I'd like to click on the failure slice and see the specific data so I can troubleshoot the problem.

I've seen people mention adding a "Search" rather than "Visualization," but this cramps the dashboard with unnecessary (in my mind) information until I need to ask for it.